# Вопрос по паттерну проектирования Стратегия

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, шаблоны-проектирования

Здравствуйте!
Имеется простое приложение, с 3 контроллами: TextBox - поле ввода, Button - кнопка "Поиск" и ListView - вывод результатов поиска. А также DataSet - набор таблиц, в которых нужно вести поиск. DataSet загружается с сервера, сразу после запуска приложения.

Поиск нужно вести в тех таблицах, в зависимости от того, что вводит пользователь. Например: если пользователь вводит "Машины", нужно искать по таблицам связанными с машинами. Если пользователь вводит "Дома" - поиск по таблицам домов. То есть заранее алгоритм поиска неизвестен.

Сейчас разбираюсь с паттернами проектирования и пытаюсь применять их на практике.
Как я понимаю, для осуществления поиска, должен подходить паттерн "Стратегия". Но для реализации этого паттерна, нужно заранее знать алгоритм поиска (стратегию).

Собственно вопрос: нужно ли в данном случае применять паттерн "Стратегия" ? Или, быть может, здесь нужен другой паттерн(ы)? Или они вообще не нужны? Как бы Вы это реализовали?

Спасибо.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    // DataSet
    private DataSet _dataSet;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Загрузка DataSet
        var dataSetLoader = DataSetLoader();
        _dataSet = dataSetLoader.Load();
    }

    // Кнопка "Поиск"
    private void SearchButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Что искать (текст)
        string search = InputTextBox.Text;
    }
}
```

Comment: Для начала, вам совершенно точно нужен паттерн MVVM. И ещё паттерн «никогда не грузить таблицу в UI-потоке, потому что иначе будет тормозить».

Comment: @VladD на самом деле, паттерн MVVM используется. И таблицы грузится через асинхронный метод. Просто упростил код, для большего понимания сути вопроса.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С шаблонами все не так просто, к сожалению. Сколько людей столько и мнений. Например я считаю, что стратегия это шаблон, который используется для решения проблемы принципа [открытия/закрытия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)), и я почти уверен что многие со мной не согласятся. Нужна ли она здесь? Наверное нет.

Как это реализовать по другому? Пользоваться принцпиом KISS. Самый простой (как по мне) вариант это  сделать несколько классов объеденных интерфейсом ISearch. В зависимости от того что ввел пользователь, просить соответствующий экземпляр класса.

С одной стороны вы избавитесь от деталей реализации поиска. С другой стороны разделите логику поиска по отдельным классам. С третьей стороны заплатите за это читаемостью кода, так как уже будет не так понятно, кто же конкретно осуществляет поиск.

Надеюсь это немного поможет.И главное - с шаблонами основное это не перебрать :)

Comment: А как насчет шаблона "Цепочка обязанностей" в данном случае?

Comment: @Вадим А вот это - попробуйте (С). Единственный минус потенциальный расход памяти так как вам придется сразу создать все хендлеры. Но не думаю что это будет критичным.